# How to control youtube videos for IOS in AS3?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, youtube

I've made an app for Android and IOS in AS3. 
The app have some youtube videos embed and I've put 3 buttons in order to control it ("play", "pause" and "back").

Everything is working for Android.

Everything is working on MY simulator for IOS.

But when I have submited the app to the Apple Store, it was rejected. The reason was that :

> We found that your app exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed
>   oniPad running iOS 7.0.6, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks, which
>   is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> When we tap "Play", "Pause" or "Retour" no further action takes place.

Weird..Don't understand why it's not working for them.

Here is my code (quite simple). Do you think there is an error somewhere ?

```
back_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Stop2, false, 0, true);
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVid);
pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseVid); 

function playVid(e:MouseEvent):void { 
my_player.playVideo(); 
} 

function pauseVid(e:MouseEvent):void { 
my_player.pauseVideo();
}

function Stop2(event:MouseEvent):void{
    my_player.stopVideo(); 
    removeChild(my_loader);
    goBack(event);
    my_loader.unload();
}
```

Is there something wrong with the code ?

Thanks !

Comment: It really is best to test your applications on the actual devices they are targeted for before release

Comment: Sure, but I don't have an Ipad (I've got an Android tablet and a Surface..I won't buy an Ipad..is there an other way ?)

Comment: If you are running on OS X, you could build to the simulator. Regardless, 68cherries is right. You should **never** release to a platform that you have not tested on, especially when it comes to mobile. Just because it is a common code base does not mean the code will behave the same on both platforms. I have iOS-specific and Android-specific bugs in my AIR apps *all the time* (I currently have 10 AIR apps in both stores with three more on the way. These bugs are not a rare thing)

Comment: Ok, I've tested the app on an Ipad (thanks to a friend) and when I'm clicking on play, pause or return, it doesn't work... Do you know what could be the problem in the code ?